# How add custom wrapper div around image preview in Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I am using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for image uploads with drag & drop functionlity. Now my question is how to add custom Wrapper/Coantainer DIV around image upload images.

[image]

**Just like this:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
    <div id="some-dropzone" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-square dz-started">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
        <div id="my-custom-div"> <! -- My custom wrapper div around preview div -->
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success">
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-image-preview">
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-image-preview">
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-image-preview">
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-image-preview">
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-image-preview">
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-image-preview">
            <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-image-preview">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want display all image with scrollbar in single row. So do you have any idea how to do that in Dropzone.js or any other way.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Try jquery wrapAll. http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

Comment: I have tried but using with wrapAll it is not adding arround my `dz-preview` div.

Comment: Can you share your js code in a fiddle? Without seeing the code, I cannot comment about the issue. Also try using jquery wrap or wrapInner

Comment: Check this fiddle but I am not able to add my custom div arround preview div. http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/1cy803ar/

Comment: I updated the fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following solution with dropzone initialize code.

```
this.on("success", function(file, serverFileName) {

     if (!$('#preview-wrapper').length){
         $(".dz-preview").wrapAll("<div id='preview-wrapper'></div>");
     }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/1cy803ar/4/

JS:

```
$('#some-dropzone').append("<div id='my-custom-div'></div>");
$('#some-dropzone #my-custom-div').append($('#some-dropzone .dz-preview'));
```

Comment: Hi. That is adding above `<div id="some-dropzone" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-square dz-started">` and I want after that div.

Comment: @Mr.Happy Please be more clear. After which div? There is difference in after,inside.

Comment: I have explain in my question with HTML view. I want to add after this div `<div id="some-dropzone" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-square dz-started">`.